# Java Custom Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to catch an exception, and then throw it.

```
try{
    arr = new class[arrLen]; //Goes to a constructor that may cause an exception
}
catch(Exception e){
    MyException e = new MyException;
    throw e;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to execute a command, and then if it causes an exception, I want to create a new instance of MyException and then throw it.

What I am having problems with is whether I am supposed to create the "Exception e" and then try and create a new "MyException e", or am I supposed to make a new MyException, AKA

```
MyException f = new MyException;
throw f;
```

Comment: Please use proper syntax in your code examples.

Comment: I'd say that it's weird to reuse `e`. Just a feeling.

Comment: What's wrong with the syntax? I'm still pretty new to this community

Comment: Why do you want to catch and throw it? A catch and throw pattern makes not much sense in most cases but you can certainly do that. - "catch an exception, and then throw it" would be when you don't create a new one. You can also catch one exception then throw a different one. Or just catch it without throwing. Or not catch it at all and let other code handle it.

Comment: @bob your syntax is incorrect and won't compile. There are several problems, and you should make sure the code compiles before pasting it into a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new `MyException` with a new variable, like `f`.  This new exception should use the original `Exception` as the cause.  For example

```
MyException f = new MyException(e);
throw f;
```

Or you can reuse the e variable if `MyException` extends Exception.

```
e = new MyException(e);
throw e;
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly :D